# Loop through array and sum and average

Tags: php, arrays, loops

#### Have an array:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => string '13.8' (length=4)
array (size=1)
  0 => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => string '44.0' (length=4)
array (size=1)
  0 => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => string '20.2' (length=4)
array (size=1)
  0 => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => string '17.8' (length=4)
```

Need to loop through the values and sum and then get the average.

I tried this to convert the values to int which was fine:

```
    $changeArray = array_map(
    function($value) { 
        return (int)$value;
    }, $totalavgarray);
```

But when I try this to get the sum, I only get the last value:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($changeArray); $i++) {
    $sum += $changeArray[$i];<br>
    echo $sum;<br>
    }
```

```
Result = 17

The desired result should be: 
SUM = 95.8
AVG = 23.9
```

---

var_export($totalavgarray) result is:

```
array ( 0 => 0, )

array ( 0 => '13.8', )

array ( 0 => 0, )

array ( 0 => '44.0', )

array ( 0 => 0, )

array ( 0 => 0, )

array ( 0 => '20.2', )

array ( 0 => 0, )

array ( 0 => '17.8', )
```

---

output of print_r($totalavgarray);

Array ( [0] => 0 )

Array ( [0] => 13.8 )

Array ( [0] => 0 )

Array ( [0] => 44.0 )

Array ( [0] => 0 )

Array ( [0] => 0 )

Array ( [0] => 20.2 )

Array ( [0] => 0 )

Array ( [0] => 17.8 )

Comment: can you post the actual array.. it would be easier to understand the structure that way..

Comment: It looks like each element of your array is another array.

Comment: array size=1 doesnt make sense if each element is array. unable to understand the array. the given sample of var_dump is confusing

Comment: This is not reproducible at all.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you have an HTML element `<br>` after the termination of a php statement

Comment: <br> element was left over from trying to figure out how to post the code in a readable way on this site.  Just ignore any HTML tags.

Comment: var dump is coming from this = $totalavgarray = array($erecstartdata2[$enumb2]);          var_dump($totalavgarray);

Comment: Sounds more like I need to figure out how to output the array in a friendlier format so I can loop through it.   I searched through this site for some kind of direction, but result was always the same.

Comment: you should do `print_r($totalavgarray)` and show us the output. It looks like you have multiple arrays, you can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: After some searching, maybe I could use "serialize" the data and then explode and then convert the data ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a `for` loop, just use a `foreach` loop.

Do:

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
    foreach($changeArray as $value) {
        $total += $value;
    }
    $average = $total/count($changeArray);
    echo "Total: {$total}<br>";
    echo "Average: {$average}";
?>
```

Comment: The result is showing the same last value = Total: 17
    Average: 17

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- Your array has its values inside nested sub arrays, so you should extract these values from that deeper level
- Your definition of average seems to mean you ignore zero values, so that means the count to be used in the average calculation should be the number of non-zero values

Here is the suggested code:

```
$totalavgarray = [ [0], ["13.8"], [0], ["44.0"], [0], [0], ["20.2"], [0], ["17.8"] ];

$sum = $count = 0;
foreach ($totalavgarray as list($val)) {
    $sum += $val;
    $count += !!$val;
}
$avg = $sum/$count;

echo "Sum: $sum\n"; // 95.8
echo "Avg: $avg\n"; // 23.95
```

Comment: Result...    Sum: 1 Avg: 1

Comment: No, see [eval.in](https://eval.in/833603). If you get something different, then please provide the *exact* output of `var_export($totalavgarray)`, because that is what I have used in the fiddle.

Comment: Using your array as you have it, the results are correct.   But when I plug in the code you provide, the result is....  Sum: 1 Avg: 1               The var_export above is exactly whats shown on the page.

Comment: Your `$totalavgarray` then is not a plain array, but an instance of some class. Could you provide the `var_dump($totalavgarray)` output? If the first output in your question is coming from  `var_dump($totalavgarray)`, then please explain where this data is coming from, because that surely is not an array.

Comment: var_dump is already shown at top of page of my post...   thanks for your effort...     I am also open to converting the array data to something else.

Comment: Convert it to an array, as currently it is not.